# Blazor inline editing table and getting all component values on event

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

On a Blazor component, I have this table in which I'm trying to implement inline editing functionality. I've managed the visual bits, but when it comes to grabbing the new values from the changed row on button click, I have no clue how to proceed.

Each row on the table is based on this object:

```
public class InstanceData 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsEditing { get; set; }
}
```

On my razor page, table is populated like following:

```
<table>
    @*<thead tbody blah blah>*@

    @foreach (var instance in serverInstances)
    {
        if (instance.IsEditing)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@instance.GetShortenedIdentifier()</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Give the instance a name" value="@instance.DisplayName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. http://localhost (without port)" value="@instance.BaseAddress" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="The port number server is running on" value="@instance.Port"
                            min="0" max="65535" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="For information purposes and not required" value="@instance.Version" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Any other details to add (e.g. Feature environment mocks instance)" value="@instance.AdditionalInformation" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="() => EnableEditing(false, instance)">
                        <i class="fas fa-window-close" />
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="() => UpdateInstance(instance)">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-square" />
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@instance.GetShortenedIdentifier()</th>
                <td>@instance.DisplayName</td>
                <td>@instance.BaseAddress</td>
                <td>@instance.Port</td>
                <td>@instance.Version</td>
                <td>@instance.AdditionalInformation</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="() => EnableEditing(true, instance)">
                        <i class="fas fa-pen" />
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>



@code {
    private void EnableEditing(bool flag, InstanceData instanceData)
    {
        instanceData.IsEditing = flag;
    }

    private void UpdateInstance(InstanceData instanceData)
    {
        EnableEditing(false, instanceData);

        //call the repository to update the instance here.
        //show toast after done.
    }
}
```

So, what I am trying to do is to get all those `input` element values to be passed into my method on `@onclick="() => UpdateInstance(instance)"` action. I've thought of assigning Id or fiddle with `@ref` but failed. What's the correct way to do this, or am I approaching this in a wrong way?

To visualise it, here's a little something with my awesome ms paint skills.
[image: blazor thingy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the input values using the object values but not binding them.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Give the instance a name" value="@instance.DisplayName" />
```

This will set the value of the input control but won't pass updates to anything.

You need to `@bind` the values to the property, e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Give the instance a name" @bind="@instance.DisplayName" />
```

This will update the underlying object's properties with any changes.

More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This for some reason did not work for me. I've ended up using "InputText" along with "EditForm" from Blazor.

Comment: @leo_acm94 weird, it works just fine for me. Make sure you remove the `value=` element as `@bind` uses it behind the scenes

Comment: @Quango did you use Blazor web assembly for this? I'm trying to get this working on blazor server, without any luck (so far). Will update if I make any progress!

Comment: @mochsner should be the same for Wasm and Server

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    value="@instance.DisplayName" 
    @onchange="@(e => CurrentDislayName = e.Value.ToString())"
    readonly="@bEditing" id="@($"id_{instance.id}")" />

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string CurrentDisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.